# Bitcoin Core transaction stay unconfirmed

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

My transaction from Bitcoin Core to Trezor Wallet stays unconfirmed. Because of too low transaction fee ? How do I resolve ?

Status: 0/unconfirmed, in memory pool, broadcast through 9 node(s)
Date: 23.08.2017 11:39
...
Transaction fee: -0.00005760 BTC
...
Transaction ID: 3d9a0ab7d39bf553584a19433280e61065225891f257cca4f9f00811939d2189
Transaction total size: 192 bytes
Output index: 0

Answer (score 0):

Found solution in related posting a looong way down into previous answers:
Make use of the free ViaBTC Transaction Accelerator service (requires a minimum fee rate of 0.0001 BTC/kB): "https://pool.viabtc.com" under "Tool".